# Select and merge a range of cells

Tags: c#, epplus

I am trying to select the range `A1` to `C3` to affect a value but this code is not working:

```
worksheet.Select["A1:C3"].Value = "toto";
```

I am able to affect the value to each of the cell with this code (but that's not what I want):

```
worksheet.Cells["A1:C3"].Value = "toto";
```

I want to **merge all cells** from `A1` to `C3`, and that this new cell contains toto value;

Comment: I want to merge all cells from a1 to c3, and that this new cell contains toto value

Comment: Try merging the cells first then?  worksheet.Select["A1:C3].Merge = true

Comment: Darren, and then affect a value to this new cell?

Comment: I've no idea without looking at the EPPlus documentation a little further.  Have you tried merging and then writing to the range as you have done so above.  As in, merge and then use your 2nd way of writing to the range.

Answer (score 4):

You first have to merge the cells like this:

```
worksheet.Cells["A1:C3"].Merge = true;
```

then to set the value you would either do this:

```
worksheet.Cells["A1:C3"].Value = "toto";
```

or set A1 to the value (since it's merged)

```
worksheet.Cells["A1"].Value = "toto";
```

Answer (score 1):

Kelsey's method is more diect but if you want to use the Select methods for some reason:

```
[TestMethod]
public void MergeCellTest()
{
    var existingFile = new FileInfo(@"c:\temp\temp.xlsx");
    if (existingFile.Exists)
        existingFile.Delete();

    using (var package = new ExcelPackage(existingFile))
    {
        var workbook = package.Workbook;
        var worksheet = workbook.Worksheets.Add("newsheet");

        worksheet.Select("A1:C3");
        worksheet.SelectedRange.Merge = true;
        worksheet.SelectedRange.Value = "toto";

        package.Save();
    }
}
```